# React: multiple state values changing a composed parent's value?

Tags: reactjs, react-props, react-state

I'm having hard time introducing `UrlInput` component in React. The main idea is to get *props*, like `url` and its setter (from parent) and split it internally into 3 `UrlInput` state values, e.g. `protocol`, `host` and `port`. `UrlInput` should use 3 form fields and change a single `url` in parent.

Simplified version:

```js
export const UrlInput = ({ url, parentSetter }) => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState({ protocol: "", host: "", port: 0 });

  useEffect(() => {
    const urlRegex = /(https?):\/\/([a-z]+):([0-9]{4,6})/;
    const [, protocol, host, port] = url.match(urlRegex);
    setFields({ protocol, host, port });
  }, [url]);

  const onChange = e => {
    setFields({ ...fields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
    parentSetter(`${fields.protocol}://${fields.host}:${fields.port}`);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="text" name="protocol" value={fields.protocol} onChange={onChange} />
      ://
      <input type="text" name="host" value={fields.host} onChange={onChange} />
      :
      <input type="number" name="port" value={fields.port} onChange={onChange} />
      <p>{JSON.stringify(fields)}</p>
    </>
  );
};
```

```js
function App({ url: initialUrl }) {
  const [url, setUrl] = useState(initialUrl);
  const [age, setAge] = useState(0);
  return (
    <>
      <input type="number" name="age" value={age} onChange={e => setAge(e.target.value)} />
      <br />
      <UrlInput url={url} parentSetter={setUrl} />
      <p>{JSON.stringify({ url, age })}</p>
    </>
  );
}
```

Current behavior:

1. First change, e.g. `protocol`: `UrlInput` state changes, parent's state does not
2. Second change, e.g. `host`: Parent synchronizes `protocol` with `UrlInput` and `UrlInput` changes have no effect
3. Same as 1
4. Same as 2

and so on. You can verify the behavior [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-tevu6w).

I want to have a simple API - just `url` and `setter`, but maybe it's not how it should be done?

Comment: answer edited, good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this code:

```js
const onChange = e => {
  const data = { ...fields, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
  setFields(data);
  parentSetter(`${data.protocol}://${data.host}:${data.port}`);
};
```